# Sending payload with sigaction

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

how can I use sigaction such that a process can send a payload with the signal that can be retrieved by the receiving process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0`), so that the signals are queued, and you have a much lesser chance of missing one. (Standard signals are not queued, so if two signals are sent at nearly the same time, only one of them is actually delivered.)

When installing the handler using `sigaction()`, you use the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, so that the signature of the handler is

```
void signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
```

When a signal is sent using [`sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html), the third parameter is a pointer or an int, stored in an union of type `union sigval`. (For `union sigval value`, the int is `value.sival_int`, and the pointer is `value.sival_ptr`. In Linux, you can send a full `long` or `unsigned long` using `value.sival_ptr = (void *)(unsigned long)yourval;`.)

(In Linux, `sizeof (long) == sizeof (void *)`, so you can actually send `CHAR_BIT*sizeof (long)` bits of information; this is 32 in 32-bit architectures, and 64 in 64-bit architectures.)

The handler can determine if a signal was sent using `sigqueue()` by checking if `info->si_code == SI_QUEUE`. The payload is then available 
in `info->si_value` union. Note that you cannot know whether the sender sent a pointer or an int, you need to know that beforehand. The [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) man page describes all the fields, including `si_code`.

Don't be confused about `->si_int`, `->si_ptr`, and `->si_value`. The `siginfo_t` structure is defined so that the members `si_int` and `si_value.sival_int` refer to the exact same `int`, and `si_ptr` and `si_value.sival_ptr` refer to the exact same `ptr`. There are some extra "names" for these fields for backwards compatibility, that's all.

Remember, at times of high load, even a realtime signal can be lost. However, we routinely use signals like `HUP` or `TERM` to tell service daemons to reload their configuration or exit; so, for similar management purposes, and for informational (as opposed to crucial) messages, using signals and their payload is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are not intended for passing an excessive data between processes. Consider another IPC mechanism, like pipes, sockets, etc.

Or alternatively you can use them in conjunction. E.g. share two ends of a pipe between processes, then write something to it in process A, then send signal to process B. Delivering of a signal to process B is treated as readiness to read from a pipe, then process B just reads data from a pipe, that were written by A.